# PHP array of unknown length with 0 as initial value

Tags: php, arrays

I have PHP `$_SESSION` arrays that have an undefined amount of elements. Is it possible to initialise all the values to 0, or do I have to check whether the value is `NULL` and then set to 0 every time I check a value?

**Edit:** I'm sorry for the vagueness of my question.
I have an undefined amount of levels, and I'd like to store all the scores of each level in that array. Currently my amount of levels is fixed, so I am currently just writing:

```
$_SESSION['totals'] = array(0,0,0,0,0);
```

And then when adding manipulating the data, I simply increment/add a certain amount to that element.

Now I'd prefer to have the same ease of directly incrementing/adding values to certain elements without needing to check whether a value is NULL or something like that...

**Edit 2:** edited my code as follows:

```
$_SESSION['totals'] = array();    
if(array_key_exists($row['level']-1,$_SESSION['totals'])){
    $_SESSION['totals'][$row['level']-1]++;
}else{
    $_SESSION['totals'][$row['level']-1] = 1;
}
```

And it seems to work. Thanks fellas!

Comment: Do you have an example? And did you try anything?

Comment: Can you illustrate your question with some code?

Comment: How you initialise undefined amount of elements? You can initialize default elements. You can do method to get the specific key from session, and if this key doesn't exist the method return 0 or something.

Comment: Clarified my question; sorry for the vagueness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used `array_key_exists()` to check if the index is set. If it is not, I display `0` or add store a certain value in that field, else I show the value of that index or add certain value to that field.

Credit to [Sven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1627406/sven) for bringing that up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_fill_keys`](http://php.net/array_fill_keys) function to fill an array with specified value for defined keys:

```
$keys   = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
$output = array_fill_keys($keys, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining an array with initial values *is* defining an array with a length. This does not prevent you from adding or removing elements from the array:

```
// initial array
$myArray = [0, 0, 0, 0];
print_r($myArray); // would output Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0)

$myArray[] = 1;
print_r($myArray); // would output Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION` contains only what *you* put into it. Just make sure you add `0` instead of `null` the first time you add something.

If you need to do this later, I think your design might be bad. But anyway, `$_SESSION` is like a normal array, so you can just use PHP's array function to traverse the array and check or change each value.

Answer (score 0):

PHP arrays aren't really arrays you might know from other languages. They really are more like linked lists with hash access.

What this means is: You either know all the string array indices you want to use, and either make sure they exist, or you check their existence every time you access them which might fail.

For numeric indices, the same thing applies. You might have an array with indices 1, 2 and 4 present, but if you run over it with only a `for` loop, you will trigger a notice when accessing the nonexistant element 3.

Use `foreach` loops whenever you want to iterate arrays. Check with `isset()` whenever you want to document that the array value might not be present. Don't do it if you know or assume that the array element MUST be present - if not, you get the notice as a reminder that your code is working on a data structure that is NOT what you thought it is. Which actually is a good thing. Then fix it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to abstract your session stuff by creating facade methods, or getters and setters around the session variables rather than access them directly. This way you can return a default value if the one you're after doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

to check what u have in your sessions, loop tru it. not sure if this is what u are asking.

```
foreach($_SESSION as $x=>$y)
{
       if(empty($x)) { //do something }
 }
```

Comment: I think `empty()` is not the best function to check whether a value is set in an array, because plenty of values that actually have a meaning and are hard to remember are considered "empty". I'd always suggest not to use `empty()`, but `isset()` - this one will report unset values or NULL as not set. And if even that should be told apart: `array_key_exists()`.

Comment: true. forgot about array_key_exist(). :)